# If I have a set of all the eigenvectors for the matrix A $ E = ${$x \in F^n s.t. Ax = \lambda x$}, how do I show $x,y \in E$ means $x+y\in E$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Also, how do I prove that if $x \in E$, then $cx \in E \forall c \in F^n$?

Comment: To show that $x+y\in E$ write $A(x+y)=Ax +Ay=\ldots$

Comment: To show that $cx\in E $ write $A(cx)=c(Ax)=\ldots$

Comment: The Question is not currently in a good condition.  You ask about one thing in the title, and in the body we find no context for that, but instead you move to a different problem.  Please use the body of the Question to give a fairly self-contained presentation of the problem you want help with, its setup and goal, and then explain to Readers the context (where the problem crops up, why it is interesting or difficult, what approach youve considered, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of $x, y \in E$ you have
$$A(x+y)=Ax+Ay=\lambda x+\lambda y = \lambda (x+y)$$
so $x+y\in E$. Similarly
$$A(cx)=c(Ax)=c\lambda x = \lambda (cx)$$
so $cx \in E$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll need to consider what an eigenvector is, and know a few things about matrix multiplication. Specifically, you'll need to know (or prove) that for any vectors $x$ and $y$ of appropriate size and for any $c\in F,$ we have $$A(x+y)=Ax+Ay$$ and $$A(cx)=c(Ax).$$